# Ionic ios App Crashing - Memory issue

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

We have a ionic cordova app built for ios and the application is some what big. And the app is working fine but sometimes in iPad 4 or other devices the application crashes saying memory warning in xcode. And we are using a timeline view similar to facebook app's newsfeed. And it contains images in each item. And this is a infinite scroll list and the list can grow very big. Currently we are using ng-repeat to populate list but we tried migrating it to collection-repeat, and the crash frequency is decreased but its still crashing. If i could find any blogs or links which will guide me through the performance tuning tips in ionic application it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I simply rebooted the simulator by going to Hardware > Reboot. That fixed my app-crashing issue. Good luck with your app!